# Обнаружить StackOverflowError в других потоках

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, prolog, стек

Я делаю интерпретатор языка Prolog. Язык основан на рекурсии, и неправильно написанные программы часто приводят к переполнению стека. Когда запускал свой интерпретатор из приложения JavaFX я заметил, что JavaFX может обнаруживать StackOverflowError в потоке и обрабатывать его.

Как самому сделать что-то подобное, чтобы определить StackOverflowError, выброшенный в другом потоке и обработать его?

[image: StackOverflowError in stacktrace]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае я бы посоветовал данную задачу (перехват ожидаемого исключения) возложить на сам поток, но если это не возможно по каким либо причинам:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyUncaughtExceptionHandler());
```

См. [setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-), [UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)

**Правка (после предоставления исходных кодов):**

Внутри установленного `UncaughtExceptionHandler`:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> errorsOutput.runtimeException(new RuntimeException("Error in program thread", throwable)));
```

Comment: Тоже нашёл эти методы, попробовал использовать их, но JavaFX всё равно перехватывает ошибку вместо моего listener-а. Пробовал даже потоку задать новую группу, всё равно каким-то образом его перехватывает JavaFX и программа зависает. Где связь между потоком, который я создаю и javafx, я не понимаю.

Comment: Составьте небольшое приложение, на котором данная ситуация воспроизводится (вместе с этим листенером). Так будет проще помочь.

Comment: Странно, создал простой javafx проект с рекурсией в потоке и листенером, всё работает. А у меня в проекте почти то же самое, но не работает. Придётся всё-таки кидать свой проект. https://github.com/FalaleevMaxim/Prolog-IDE Листенер в классе Controller на 145 строке. Введите и запустите в приложении такую программу: 
`predicates
p
clauses
p:-p.
goal
p`